# how to find the average of sales per city?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Let's say we have a dataset like this:

```
 id        sales    city
 12        10000    New york
 13        15000    New york
 14        20000    Tokyo
 15        25000    Tokyo
 16        10000    Istanbul
 17        12000    Istanbul
```

How I can find the average sales per city?

Using this, I want to create a horizontal bar graph.

Comment: group by city and then find the average

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
print(df.groupby('city')['sales'].mean())
```